# Jenkins installation error on Centos7 - File contains no section headers

Tags: jenkins, installation, centos

During my first installation of Jenkins on CentOS7, I've encountered this tough problem.

```js
File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo, line: 1
'--2018-05-25 10:51:24-- http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat/jenkins.repo\n'
```

After Googling and searching related issues in Stackoverflow, finally I got an answer 'there was an extra space in repo file', however not sure where 'the extra space' is in exactly. Please let me know where the invisible bomb in here. Thanks,